How to disable setting bottom offset for MessagesCollectionView using MessageKit?
I have implemented MessageKit cocoapods library to display chat views in my app. I simply replaced default inputyAccessoryView with my own one.
This is how my controller is build:
class ConversationViewController: MessagesViewController
    override var inputAccessoryView: UIView? {
        nil
    }
    ...


    reactiveKeyboard.observeKeyboardHeight(onNext: { [weak self] keyboardVisibleHeight in
        self?.mainView.updateOffset(keyboardVisibleHeight: keyboardVisibleHeight)
        // that method is called when frame for keyboard changes and just update bottom offset for my inputTextField. That is all. It works correctly as you can see. collectionView for messages is sticked to the top of my inputTextField and there should not be any additional offsets there. How can I disable it?
    }, disposedBy: disposeBag)
}

Since I manually set my offset from the bottom, I do not need automatic offset for that view.
This is how it look like when keyboard is hidden (it is ok ✅):

and when keyboard is visible (it is not ok ❌, indicator for bottom of the scroll you can see on the right side):

